# Custom sun position

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Arcgis javascript API calculates sun position based on provided date:
`view.environment.lighting.date`

and renders the scene accordingly.

Is there a way how to provide custom sun position calculation algorithm?

Comment: At the moment this is not possible with the JavaScript API. May I ask what your use case is?

Comment: @ArnoFiva our use case is that we have specific algorithm for calculating sun position based on datetime. This algorithm is used in other parts of our system for various calculations and we want visualisation part to be aligned with the rest of the system.

Comment: Can you elaborate how that algorithm is different to the actual sun position? You can rely on the JavaScript API positioning the sun and the stars realistically.

Comment: @ArnoFiva there are several algorithms for calculating sun position with various accuracy and computational complexity and maybe fine tuned algorithms that tweak the sun position a bit. What you mean by realistically? How accurate it is? What algorithm is used? I looked through API documentation and couldn't find which algorithm is used.

Comment: The library used in the API is this one: https://github.com/mourner/suncalc. You can find the complete list of external libraries in the copyright.txt file: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-js-api/blob/4master/copyright.txt

Comment: @ArnoFiva thank you, i somehow missed that. You can add your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point the ArcGIS API for JavaScript does not provide a way to override the sun position. The library used by the API to compute the sun position is https://github.com/mourner/suncalc.